# Getting CS0843 (backing field must be assigned) when calling constructor of struct

Tags: c#, properties, struct, constructor

I am trying to replicate .NET's Color `struct`, which lets you call colors using `Color.Black`, `Color.White` etc. Here's my code:

```
    struct Material
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        public Material(string filepath) { FilePath = filepath; }

        public static Material Sand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Material("images/sand");
            }
        }

        public static Material Conrete
        {
            get
            {
                return new Material("images/conrete");
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error saying I cannot use a constructor in a `struct`. I am effectively copying from the .NET source code (Color.cs) and this is how it does it, although it doesn't use a constructor. The static properties do return a `new Material()` however.

Full error message appearing on constructor [CS0843](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513821.aspx):

```
backing field for automatically implemented property must be fully assigned before it is returned to the caller
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: The error you get isn't telling you you can't use a constructor, it's telling you that you can't call a method (even a property setter) on a struct that isn't fully initialised. Pay better attention to what the compiler tells you. :)

Comment: Full error is "backing field for automatically implemented property must be fully assigned before it is returned to the caller"

Comment: I've also edited your post to make title more specific and include error code (plus link to explanation if you want to learn more). Note that you could easily get to the MSDN article from Visual Studio by pressing "F1" when error message is selected.

Comment: Side note: make sure you understand how `struct` behaves in C# - in most cases regular `class` is easier to get right.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply "chain" `this()`, as in:

```
public Material(string filepath)
  : this()
{
  FilePath = filepath;
}
```

and this is the most common solution.

Of course you can do the same in other ways:

```
public Material(string filepath)
{
  this = default(Material);
  FilePath = filepath;
}
```

and

```
public Material(string filepath)
{
  this = new Material { FilePath = filepath, };
}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN have a constructor, just not one with zero arguments.

However, isn't it clearer to write

```
new Material { FilePath = "images/concrete" }
```

instead of

```
new Material("images/concrete");
```

A custom constructor can always be bypassed by invoking the framework-provided parameterless constructor, so it can't be relied on for setting up invariants.  And fields and properties can be set using member-initialization syntax.  So struct constructors aren't terribly useful.

Comment: You: _So struct constructors aren't terribly useful_ Strongly disagree. Have you never used a constructor of `DateTime` or of `Guid`, to mention examples? Remember that most `struct` are immutable (mutable structs are considered evil), so your idea of just setting each instance member manually after creating the instance will fail in almost all realistic scenarios. Of course one can use `static` Create methods instead of instance constructors, but it is normally not advantageous.